# add an item to cart

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a small app that searches an item from list, displays it's price and multiplies it by the quantity. Below that I added an add button. Now I want the item with its price and quantity to add under the button (to make something like a shopping cart, basically), but I'm struggling with the code, it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>app</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,400italic, 700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body  layout="column" ng-controller="autoCompleteController">
      <div>
     <h1>Purchase Order</h1>
      <div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex><h4>Name</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Quantity</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Price</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Total</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex>
           <md-autocomplete flex 
              md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
              md-search-text="searchText" 
              md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
              md-item-text="item.name" 
              placeholder="Product name"
              md-min-length="0">
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>
          </div>
          <div flex>
          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
          <input ng-model="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div flex><p>{{selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
          <div flex><p>{{quantity * selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.name}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.price}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.qty}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.totAmt}}</p>
        </div>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="AddInCart()">Add item</md-button>
      </div>
</div>
   <script src="../src/api.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    myApp.controller('autoCompleteController', function($scope) {     
        $scope.querySearch = function() {
            return $scope.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchText));
        };
        $scope.AddInCart = function() {
            var itemName = $scope.products.name;
            var itemPrice = parseInt($scope.products.price);
            var itemQty = parseInt($scope.quantity);
            var totalPrice = parseInt(itemPrice * itemQty);
            var jsonCartItem = {
                'name' : itemName,
                'price' : itemPrice,
                'qty' : itemQty,
                'totAmt' : totalPrice
            };
            $scope.products.push(jsonCartItem);
        };

        $scope.products = [
            {name:"Worn Shortsword",price:3}
            /*4000 other products here */
           ,{name:"Annealed Blade",price:12980}
        ];
    });
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/VjqJYW

Comment: that code doesn't make sense.  `$scope.products` is an array, it doesn't have `.name`, `.price`, etc.  You *probably* want the `selectedItem` instead.

Comment: Do you want to add add items it `$scope.products` to cart?

Comment: I'll make a codepen so you'll see what I want exactly to do

Comment: I added a codepen in my question

Comment: your code is working fine. What is you exactly want to do? you are adding items to cart but you are not displaying it is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    myApp.controller('autoCompleteController', function($scope) {      
      $scope.selectedItems = [];
        $scope.querySearch = function() {
            return $scope.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchText));
        };
        $scope.AddInCart = function() {
            var itemName = $scope.selectedItem.name;
            var itemPrice = parseInt($scope.selectedItem.price);
            var itemQty = parseInt($scope.quantity);
            var totalPrice = parseInt(itemPrice * itemQty);
            var jsonCartItem = {
                'name' : itemName,
                'price' : itemPrice,
                'qty' : itemQty,
                'totAmt' : totalPrice
            };
            $scope.selectedItems.push(jsonCartItem);
          console.log($scope.selectedItems);
        };

        $scope.products = [
    {name:"Worn Shortsword",price:3}
    ,{name:"Bent Staff",price:4}
   ,{name:"Worn Mace",price:3}
   ,{name:"Worn Axe",price:3}
             ,{name:"Revelosh's Armguards",price:4500}
   ,{name:"Revelosh's Spaulders",price:6725}
   ,{name:"Revelosh's Gloves",price:4534}
   ,{name:"The Shoveler",price:16164}
   ,{name:"Annealed Blade",price:12980}
];
    });
```

```css
body {
    max-width: 720px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 2em auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serfi;
}

div.row > * {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.row {
    position: relative;
}


div.row > *:nth-child(n + 3) {
    text-align: right;
}

button {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

input {
    padding: 0.4em;
}

md-autocomplete {
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
  
 <html lang="en">
   <body  ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="autoCompleteController" layout="column" >
      <div>
     <h1>Purchase Order</h1>
      <div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex><h4>Name</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Quantity</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Price</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Total</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex>
           <md-autocomplete flex 
              md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
              md-search-text="searchText" 
              md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
              md-item-text="item.name" 
              placeholder="Product name"
              md-min-length="0">
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>
          </div>
          <div flex>
          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
          <input ng-model="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div flex><p>{{selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
          <div flex><p>{{quantity * selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.name}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.price}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.qty}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.totAmt}}</p>
        </div>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="AddInCart()">Add item</md-button>
      </div>
      <h4>Added Items</h4>
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedItems">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.qty}}</td>
          <td>{{item.totAmt}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
   <script src="../src/api.js"></script>
  </body>
```

As @Dinesh Shah explained, you can access array elements only by using index.

One more mistake what I could see is when clicking on "add to cart" button, you are trying to push "jsonCartItem" into the master collection "$scope.products" which is wrong.

"$scope.products" is the master collection of items.

You should initialise one more scope variable something like below

```
$scope.addedItems = [];
```

and then probably

```
$scope.addedItems.push(jsonCartItem);
```

Comment: I added a codepen so you can better visualise what I'm trying to do

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    myApp.controller('autoCompleteController', function($scope) {      
      $scope.selectedItems = [];
        $scope.querySearch = function() {
            return $scope.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchText));
        };
        $scope.AddInCart = function() {
            var itemName = $scope.selectedItem.name;
            var itemPrice = parseInt($scope.selectedItem.price);
            var itemQty = parseInt($scope.quantity);
            var totalPrice = parseInt(itemPrice * itemQty);
            var jsonCartItem = {
                'name' : itemName,
                'price' : itemPrice,
                'qty' : itemQty,
                'totAmt' : totalPrice
            };
            $scope.selectedItems.push(jsonCartItem);
          console.log($scope.selectedItems);
        };

        $scope.products = [
    {name:"Worn Shortsword",price:3}
    ,{name:"Bent Staff",price:4}
   ,{name:"Worn Mace",price:3}
   ,{name:"Worn Axe",price:3}
             ,{name:"Revelosh's Armguards",price:4500}
   ,{name:"Revelosh's Spaulders",price:6725}
   ,{name:"Revelosh's Gloves",price:4534}
   ,{name:"The Shoveler",price:16164}
   ,{name:"Annealed Blade",price:12980}
];
    });
```

```css
body {
    max-width: 720px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 2em auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serfi;
}

div.row > * {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.row {
    position: relative;
}


div.row > *:nth-child(n + 3) {
    text-align: right;
}

button {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

input {
    padding: 0.4em;
}

md-autocomplete {
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
  
 <html lang="en">
   <body  ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="autoCompleteController" layout="column" >
      <div>
     <h1>Purchase Order</h1>
      <div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex><h4>Name</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Quantity</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Price</h4></div>
          <div flex><h4>Total</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div layout="row">
          <div flex>
           <md-autocomplete flex 
              md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
              md-search-text="searchText" 
              md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
              md-item-text="item.name" 
              placeholder="Product name"
              md-min-length="0">
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>
          </div>
          <div flex>
          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
          <input ng-model="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div flex><p>{{selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
          <div flex><p>{{quantity * selectedItem.price}}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.name}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.price}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.qty}}</p>
                       <p>{{jsonCartItem.totAmt}}</p>
        </div>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="AddInCart()">Add item</md-button>
      </div>
</div>
   <script src="../src/api.js"></script>
  </body>
```

you are doing some mistakes in your code

like $scope.products is array and you can not access it without index
you should specify which product you want to add

for example here i am using 0 index , so each time it will get first product from products array.

```
var itemName = $scope.products[0].name;
var itemPrice = parseInt($scope.products[0].price);
var itemQty = parseInt($scope[0].quantity);
var totalPrice = parseInt(itemPrice * itemQty);
```

change these lines in your code , and specify  selected product in products array.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I added a codepen so you can better visualise what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you have done some mistakes in codepen , change this line $scope.selectedItem.push(jsonCartItem) with $scope.selectedItems.push(jsonCartItem);  nd declare the variable 
$scope.selectedItems = []; inside controller

Comment: I did, but still nothing

Comment: here is the working codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXzKwr?editors=1111   , check in console i have printed the selected items in console.

Comment: yes  , what type of error you are getting in console ?

Comment: No errors, just "Array [ Object ]" prints out in the console when I click the button

Comment: Run the snippet and check console @Dorota.

Comment: Ok, it works in the codepen console, I was looking at the browser's console. How do I push it to the HTML though?

Comment: html though ? what do you exactly want ?

Comment: check out  Srujan Reddy's answer